# Setting default editor for php files

Tags: nautilus, php, netbeans, nemo

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 TLS. I had installed Netbeans on my PC. I want change default file to netbeans.

I've tried to right-click on a php file > Properties > Open With > Show other Application ; but there is no netbeans anywhere.

How can I set the default program for opening php files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using thunar should help us.

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

runnig thunar in terminal and using it for default application would be effective.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to install properly last version of [**NetBeans** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/netbeans/). After go in Nautilus where are your php files, right click on a php file, select **Open With** > **Other application** and you should find there NetBeans. Open with it.

If still you have problems, go in `/usr/share/applications/` and create with root privileges a `.desktop` file with next things in:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=<Netbeans>
Exec=<command to run program - something like /opt/netbeans/run.sh> %U
Type=Application
```

Another way would be if you open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run:

```
netbeans [ options ] [ files ]
```

See `man netbeans` for more informations.

Comment: I had installed Javascript 7.3 but Ubuntu Software Center has ver 7.1. I installed version 7.1 too, but there is not any changes. How can I modify defualt applications for .php .css .js and ...?

Comment: `~$ man netbeans
man: can't resolve /usr/share/man/man1/netbeans.1.gz: No such file or directory
man: can't resolve /usr/share/man/man1/netbeans.1.gz: No such file or directory
No manual entry for netbeans
`

Comment: I installed netbeans with `sudo apt-get install netbeans` so this command changed. So as entering `netbeans` command in terminal netbeans 7.0.1 is starting. There is two problem, firstly I installed ver 7.3 and self installing created ver 7.0 too. secondly as right click netbeans 7.3 is in the openning with list, but is not defualt. also as clicking on more applications list, there is not netbeans 7.3 nor ver 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Use this Command to Add Netbeans in Open With Menu and Default Editor:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/netbeans.desktop
```

Now Paste following Code on the Editor and Save It :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Netbeans
Comment=Netbeans IDE
Exec=/home/compaq/netbeans-8/bin/netbeans [Here you have to paste your Netbeans Path]
Icon=/home/compaq/netbeans-8/nb/netbeans.png [paste your Netbeans logo path]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development,IDE;
StartupNotify=false
```