# IntelliJ Icons (Pycharm, CLion) suddenly gone from Gnome Dashboard

Tags: gnome, launcher, pycharm

Today when I started my computer, all the IntelliJ Apps were suddenly gone from the Gnome dashboard. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and currently have PyCharm and CLion installed.

As suggested in almost all the posts I've read about this problem I deleted all relevant `*.desktop` entries from the file system, opened Pycharm and did `Tools > Create Desktop Entry`. Even after a restart, this did not help. Also making the `.desktop` file executable did not help.

I noticed that the IntelliJ `.desktop` files lie in the directory `~/.gnome/apps/`, while e.g. the Firefox `.desktop` file is in `/usr/share/applications/` and/or `/usr/share/app-install/desktop`. Hence I manually copied the files there, restarted the computer, but still no changes in the dashboard. So, what else could have caused this problem?

Comment: Did you perhaps uninstall IntelliJ or [change your default editor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/300852/setting-default-editor-for-php-files)?

Comment: @ElderGeek I don't know why this is related to my default editor, but your link helped me anyway :) As mentioned in one of the answers I created a completely new `.desktop` file in `/sur/share/applications/` and after that it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted! Feel free to write up a step by step solution in the answer box so that others with the same issue can find an answer! That will be thanks enough for me! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the link provided by Elder Geek in a comment to my question, the following solved my problem (exemplary done for CLion):

Find all `.desktop` files related to CLion:

```
sudo find / -name '*clion*.desktop'
```

Delete those files, then open CLion manually and go to `Tools > Create Desktop Entry ...`. This created the file in `~/.gnome/apps/jetbrains-clion.desktop` but it did not yet solve the problem. Next go to `/usr/share/applications` and create the file `clion.desktop` with sudo privileges. In this file enter:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=CLion
Icon=/path/to/clion/bin/clion.svg
Exec=/path/to/clion/bin/clion.sh
Type=Application
```

and hit save. Note that only creating this file without going to `Tools > Create Desktop Entry ...` was not enough for the icon to appear back in the Gnome Dash.

Thanks to Elder Geek for providing the link!